# regex pattern for http url without quotes in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

i am using this code, but it only looks for URLs with " "

```
Dim html As String = txtSource.Text
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, """(http://.+?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For Each m As Match In mc
lstReapedLinks.Items.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

Comment: removing the double quotes at the begging and at the end of the regex pattern seems like the way to go

Comment: no its not.. it just get the single letter after //. for http://yahoo.com, it returns http://y

Comment: Yep, that's probably because you are using lazy quantifier instead of greedy one. Try this: `Regex.Matches(html, "(http://.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Also it would help if you specify what kind of source you are parsing and what exactly are you trying to match in this source. It looks like your might have several urls in the source text and you want to capture them all, but you are not specifying how individual urls are separated, etc. One needs to know that type of things to create a proper regular expression.

Comment: it did not extract anything from:

<a href=http://img180.----------.com/img.php?image=----------_353_1000_123_871lo.jpg
 >Next>></a>

Comment: well i am extracting all the http link from a webpage

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to parse HTML with Regex. You might want to have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to have multiple URL's in your string then you need to define what will be their separator, for example, a blank space `some text http://abc http://123 nonurltext` or like it seems to be the case based on your regex `some text(http://abc) some other text (http://123) some more text`, once you have this delimeter, then you can use it to tell regex how to zero in on the string you really want.  The following will get **http://...** if it's enclosed in parenthesis, like `(http://www.yahoo.com)` ignoring everything else

```
Regex.Matches(test, "(?<=\()http://.+?(?=\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

You should be able to just change this to suit your needs, for example if your delimeter were blank spaces, then just replace `\(` and `\)` with `\s` (means blank space)